# Javascript function doesn't load on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that you can see here

```
function tot() {
 for(var i=1;i<13;i++) {
 var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('c'+i).innerHTML);
 var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('k'+i).innerHTML);
 var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('w'+i).innerHTML);
 var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById('g'+i).innerHTML);

 var e = a+b+c+d;
 document.getElementById('t'+i).innerHTML = e;
 }
}
```

As you can see, I only need to do calculate the result between a+b+c+d. The HTML code of the elements is the following:

```
<label id="c1">0</label>
<label id="k1">0</label>
<label id="w1">0</label>
<label id="g1">0</label>
<br />
<label id="t1">0</label>
<br />
<label id="c2">0</label>
<label id="k2">0</label>
<label id="w2">0</label>
<label id="g2">0</label>
<br />
<label id="t2">0</label> ...
```

The labels' values of c, k, w and g increments until 12. The problem is that when I call this function on Firefox, it works perfectly but wh I use google Chrome, it doesn't. I don't see any calculation.

Do you know why?

I the function is stored in an external file called `conti.js` and I call it in this way:

```
<script src="conti.js"></script>
```

That code is inside the  tag. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ6kp/)

Comment: Where are you calling the function? Add that code.

Comment: I've edited the question. I have 'conti.js' that contains all the function I need. Also, I use '<script src="conti.js"></script>' to call it.

Comment: `<script src="conti.j"></script>` should be placed after your markup.

Comment: That is not the code for calling a function. It should be like `onClick = tot();` in html or `tot();` in the js file.

Comment: And why it works on Firefox? @DarkAshelin

Comment: @AlbertoRossi I suspect the shown code here is uncomplete. In your given example, you are only declaring the functions, but are never calling them.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ6kp/ --> here you can find all the javascript code + the rest of CSS and HTML

Comment: @AlbertoRossi `tot();` in your `bdaygirl()` function is the call. Now you need to make sure that `bdaygirl()` and your other functions are also properly called so `tot()` is actually executed.

Comment: make this as complete answer, so I can accept it